# broadcast audio over HTTP like a radio station

Tags: php, http, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I'm tearing my hair out on this one so thought I'd ask over here. I'd like a PHP script that will allow me to broadcast my audio files over HTTP like a radio station.

I've tried [xmoovstream](http://stream.xmoov.com/) and its great but I can't figure out if it can be set up to broadcast audio radio-like. It currently only allows me to stream audio, i'd like it to allow me to start a track and add listeners at anytime in the track playback.

Has anyone any pointers or suggestions?

Many Thanks,
Benny

Comment: your link not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could check out some specialized streaming software instead, like Shoutcast or the like.

Comment: thanks for the advice Emil. I tried quite a few things, ffmpeg and vlc included but couldn't get what I need working. I might come back to this problem again but for now I've got other projects to work on. Thanks again!